# Do - Catch error handling Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, try-catch

I have read through numerous posts regarding conversion between older versions of swift and swift 2.0 on the issue of Do-catch error handling. However each and every one of them seem different to my personal issue.

Besides solving my personal issue I'm fairly curious as to what the general idea is behind this concept, because I simply can not figure out how this works on a low level scale just by reading all these topics.

I'll post my personal issue below, but I'd also very much appreciate some sort of general explanation about how this do-catch method works.

```
            if(urlResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                self.tweets =   NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
                    error: &jsonParseError) as? NSMutableArray
            }
```

the error shows at the line:

```
error: &jsonParseError) as? NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
if(urlResponse.statusCode == 200) {
    do {
        self.tweets = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSMutableArray
    } catch let jsonParseError {
        print("Parse error = \(jsonParseError)")
    }
}
```

You can find more about error handling [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: Thank you, that works. Thanks as well for linking this page. I'm sad for getting yet another down vote on my question, just like I did on my last one (which is still not answered). It is seriously discouraging for asking any future questions on here and does not create the feeling of a friendly environment to learn.